# wi-fi disconnected during crouton installation

Tags: chromebook, crouton, crouton-os

I purchased an Asus c300m with the soul aim of developing my linux skills

I followed the instruction to boot in developer mode and execute the following command to start downloading downloading crouton/ubuntu on it

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce
```

it was going well until my wifi disconnected temporary and i got the following error:

> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
>   Failed to complete chroot setup
>   Unmounting /mtn.stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise..

Then I tried to run the sudo command again but I got the following:

> /usr/local/chroots/precise already has stuff in it!
>   Either delete it, specify a different name (-n) or specify -u to update it

However, I'm not sure how to modify the command so i can resume installation or restart it.

Comment: @Marged the instruction tells me to try -u but i don't know how to modify the command to add -u. do I just enter -u at the next prompt?

Answer (score 1):

You could try **`sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -u -n xfce`** but it's unlikely that will work. [That's from the Crouton docs](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton#a-new-version-of-crouton-came-out-my-chroot-is-therefore-obsolete-and-sad).

The best approach, since you never finished installing and therefore don't need to recover any data, **just delete the install directory and start again.** There is no good way for crouton the pick up where it left off.

Also during the install **you don't want the Chromebook going to sleep**. There is no way in the built-in ChromeOS settings to prevent that but [according to this article](http://www.omgchrome.com/extension-to-stop-chromebook-sleeping/) you can go to [the Chrome Web Store and install Keep Awake from Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keep-awake/bijihlabcfdnabacffofojgmehjdielb).

This gives a cool icon in the upper right of the Chrome browser showing a sun, a sunset or a moon depending on what settings you want. Before you start your next install, click it to the sun so the machine won't sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I ran this and it's downloading:

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -e -t xfce -u
```

I'm not sure if it's where i left off but it is definitely downloading and reinstalling after the interrupted connection.

Answer (score 0):

Just type in sudo start[desktop environment]
and press y. It should keep going.